# Convert Image in to numbers

Tags: php, image, converters

Using PHP or any other web-tools, is there a way we can convert an image in to a numeric representation, depending on its colors. For example, if I have .jpg  .tiff, .gif, .bmp files, can I turn that image in to a file that only contain number. Where each of these numbers will correspond to a color? any help would be greatly appriciated.

For ex:

[image]

Comment: You would need to be specific about what sort of image to number conversion you are looking to do, after all, a digital image is nothing but a set of numbers anyway. As a starting point, I would point you to GDlib for PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and ImageMagick (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). These should give you the base tools you need.

Comment: @MikeBrantThank for your comment and explaining to me in detail. That helps me clear things out. You said digital images are nothing but a set of numbers. Can you please tell me, with what software should I open those images to see numbers. If I open with notepad, it doesn't show numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **PHP**. The following example asumes it's a JPG file, but could be replaced with another file type.

```
<?php

$image = 'path/to/image.jpg';

$colorArray = array();

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);

for($i=0;$i<$height;$i++) {

    for($j=0;$j<$width;$j++) {

        $color = imagecolorat($im, $j, $i);
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color);

        $colorArray[] = array('width' => $j, 'height' => $i, 'red' => $color['red'], 'green' => $color['green'], 'blue' => $color['blue'], 'alpha' => $color['alpha']);

    }

}

print_r( $colorArray );

?>
```

Comment: +1 And if the image is grey-scale, you only need one of the R/G/B values. And normalizing is simply dividing the number through 255.